# Automatic playing cards suit replacement on Android browser?

Tags: android, html, css, browser

I noticed a strange behavior on my recently upgraded HTC One (4.3) - 
Whenever I use one of the suits ASCII character (heart, spade, club, diamond), the browser automatically replaces them to a card like design.

I attached a screenshot from the phone and the link to the page where you can see for yourself.

I only saw it on my phone and not any others, on debugger it looks like plain ASCII and no CSS design can be found.

Important to say - It does not happen on Chrome for Android, but only on the default browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>♠♣♥♦</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone encountered this behavior, and more important, how to disable it?

[Example page](http://s-goldy.com/suits.html)

[Screenshot from mobile](http://s-goldy.com/suits.png)

Comment: it may be included in the font itself. how does it behave in another application?

Comment: @njzk2 I tested with Arial and Times New Roman. No Joy. Still replaces.

Comment: possibly because these characters may not be included in those fonts ?

Comment: As far as I can tell they both have those symbols in them.

Comment: You need to include valid code to reproduce the problem (and explain what you mean by suit characters – they do not exist in ASCII).

Comment: I added the code, and the picture of how it shows on my phone

Comment: Have you tried to use a web font which includes for sure those symbols? Can you select and copy the text? What happens if you paste it in a different application? However I couldn't reproduce it on an Android 2.3 device, normal plain glyphs are shown.

Comment: @CarloCannas I've tried using a web font that includes them. The device still replaces the chars to card-like.

Comment: I've got the same dispaly on my HTC One (4.3).
I think it's coming from HTC. Now to know how to disable it... you could try the HTC support

Comment: You probably wouldn't be asking if it wasn't, but is it that big of a deal? Do you have to have it show up as suits not cards? And since it shows up fine on computers, will most of your audience be on mobile?

Answer (score 4):

I opened the following site on my HTC One X (with Android 4.3) http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2660/index.htm and your link, and I could see the ♠ character perfectly, no substitution. So it's not an HTC thing nor an Android thing. Maybe you have something installed in your device that causes it? A custom keyboard? A browser extension?

Comment: In this website I see the replacement happens as well. So we ruled out HTC and 4.3. There might either be HTC One 4.3 or my phone, though I tried factory reset.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is your problem or not, but it is worth a try.

When I was learning HTML, I read that it is best to use numbers instead of names, so you could try replacing the numbers for the suits instead of names, and it might fix it.

Here they are:

```
&#9824; = ♠
&#9827; = ♣
&#9829; = ♥
&#9830; = ♦
```

And if you want to use the names, here's the list:

```
&spades;    = ♠
&clubs;     = ♣
&hearts;    = ♥
&diams;     = ♦
```

It is always good to use the numbers instead of names, or just pasting it in. If you don't do that, then you sometimes have cross-browser compatibility issues.

EDIT: 
Here is a sloppy way of doing it, but it would work. You could just put images of the suits in your webpage.

```
<p><a href="spades">...</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as far as the rendering goes - it's the same.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll see if I can find anything else.

Comment: I looked for anything that would help you, but I can't find anything that would fix it. Remember to always use numbers instead of names, and that will fix cross-browser problems.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an android phone to test this but try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<body>
    <h1>&spades;&clubs;&hearts;&diams;</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tested, still replaces. I'm beginning to think it's an HTC thing as I didn't see it on another Android 4.3.

Comment: Must be in the HTC then, if its really bugging you you can look through the en string files and see if it declares it in their somewhere.

Comment: Care to explain how to do it? Sounds promising. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a browser extension or custom font that the browser is using.
You could try opening Application manager/All and disable custom fonts that are on the device. Icon is orange with ff on it on Samsung Galaxy S3 but it will probably be something similar on HTC.

Also you could try writing out some of those spades on the HTML by modifying DOM from javascript and see if same thing happens.